# Accessibility: TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED state

Tags: android

I've written an app using an accessibilityService.

I've found that I can detect when notifications appear in the notification bar, but cannot work out how to trigger when they get cleared.

According to the android api docs:

> TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED 
>   "Represents the event showing/hiding a
>   Notification. "

..so I'm confused to why the onAccessibilityEvent only ever seems to get fired when showing an event, but not hiding one.

I'm registering the service with the following:

```
    AccessibilityServiceInfo localAccessibilityServiceInfo = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
    localAccessibilityServiceInfo.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPES_ALL_MASK;   //monitor all, then we can           
    localAccessibilityServiceInfo.notificationTimeout = 80L;
    localAccessibilityServiceInfo.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.DEFAULT;
    setServiceInfo(localAccessibilityServiceInfo);
```

Does anyone know why this would not pick up on the hiding of a notification?

Answer (score 1):

Running into the same problem over here.

I assume you're the same Andrew that filed the bug report here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18763 - I'm eager to know if anyone has discovered any workarounds.

Comment: It's been a few years now, so is it possible now to differentiate between the creation of a notification and clearing it?